# How to map/loop 2 array values to an anchor tag with href and text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map values from 2 different arrays, one which contains **links** and the other with **tab names**. I have an **anchor tag** which consists of **href** and **text** string. Is there a way I can map/loop the values from 2 arrays to supply value. App is built in React.

arrays

```
const links = ['#all', '#aew', '#roh', '#impact']
const tabnames = ['All', 'AEW', 'ROH', 'Impact']

const classnames = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
```

code

```
<a 
 href='#link' 
>
  tabname
</a>
```

What happens if I try to map 3 arrays on my **a**, one more for **classnames**?

code

```
<a 
 href='#link'
 className='classname'
>
 tabname
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.map()` and pass it a function with 2 parameters, the map function can have up to 3 parameters, `.map((element, [index], [array]) => ...)`, index and array are optional, the index can be used to access the element of the 2nd array

Here is a code snipped which should work for you (adjusted to edited answer):

```
...

{
  links.map((elem, index) => (
    <a href={elem} className={classnames[index]}>{tabnames[index]}</a>
  ))
}

...
```

---

If it is possible, I would recommend to combine all your arrays to an array of objects, since all elements with the same index are used together, so combining them would make sense, this would look something like this:

```
const links = [{
    href: '#all',
    tabName: 'All',
    className: 'One'
  },{
    href: '#aew',
    tabName: 'AEW',
    className: 'Two'
  },{
    href: '#roh',
    tabName: 'ROH',
    className: 'Three'
  },{
    href: '#impact',
    tabName: 'Impact',
    className: 'Four'
}];

...

{
  links.map((el) => (
    <a href={el.href} className={el.className}>{el.tabName}</a>
  ))
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please provide an example for a use case which has 3 arrays to be mapped,  a className on the same anchor?

Comment: @Jayesh you can just acces your 3rd array via index again `thirdArr[index]`, same as with `tabnames` in my snippet
do you explicitly need 3 arrays or would combining all arrays to an object also be an option, this would make things way easier to work with and also easier to read your code in later stages?

Answer (score 2):

You can use map()

```js
const links = ["#all", "#aew", "#roh", "#impact"];
const tabnames = ["All", "AEW", "ROH", "Impact"];

const output = links.map((el, i) => (<a href={el}>{tabnames[i]}</a>));
```